# Is it possible to update a column with the number of non empty cells of the current row?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Is it possible to update a column with the number of non empty cells of the current row?

In this example - after the update - the values in the "count non-empty cells" column would be `2`, `1` and `3` (excluding the "id" column).

```
 id | x | y | z | count non-empty cells
----|---|---|---|----------------------
  1 | a | b |   |
----|---|---|---|----------------------
  2 | c |   |   |
----|---|---|---|----------------------
  3 | d | e | f |
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using `COALESCE` here:

```
SELECT id, x, y, z,
    (CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN y IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN z IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS non_empty_count
FROM yourTable;
```